# Problem iterating and saving html-content into csv

Tags: selenium, csv, for-loop

## imports

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

today = date.today()

now = today.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

from datetime import date
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY
```

## I want to check every day, so I make the urls with the dates

```
kurl1 = ('https://www.matterhornparadise.ch/de/Buchen/Online-Tickets/Skipass-Zermatt?from=') 
kurl2 = ('&to=')
kurl3 = ('#ticketCategory')

#three days
a = date(2019, 12, 1)
b = date(2019, 12, 3)
```

## here I create a list with all the urls, so I can open each one of them via selenium

```
urllst = []

for dt in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=a, until=b):
    datum = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    
    liste = kurl1 +datum +kurl2+datum +kurl3
    
    urllst.append(liste)
```

## and now I want to get all the three htmls in one single html file. but it overwrites. Can anyone help?

```
for jede in urllst:
    driver.get(jede)
    schreib1 = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
    schreib2 = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
    schreib3 = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')


    with open('Daten_zermatt_'+now+'.htm', 'wb+') as file:
        file.write(schreib1+schreib2+schreib3) 
        file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO.

There are missing parts in your code - hence, I can't reproduce exactly the behavior of your code - but there is a logical fallacy I can see in the last block: you are extracting three times the **same** page source (note that, within the for loop, you `driver.get` once, while you extract the `page_source` thrice); finally, you write down the three equal html files in a single one.

Below a code snippet which extracts the source of two different pages and stores them in a single html file - which, by the way, is nearly unreadable:

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")

urllist = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.bing.com']

with open('foo.html', 'wb+') as g:
    for url in urllist:
        browser.get(url) # get the i-th url
        schreib = browser.page_source.encode('utf-8') # extract its source
        g.write(schreib) # write it on the html
    g.close()
browser.close()
```

To sum up: you need to open the html file **outside** the loop, and then write the source file one by one within the loop.

As a final remark, I strongly recommend you **not** to store several html pages in a single local file: just write one file per page, in order to avoid problems.

Comment: Happy to have been helpful - if you used the answer, please mark the question as solved.

Comment: Bump to close the thread and accept the answer @FabianvonAllmen